# Changing the format of ActionMenu

Tags: button

I am attempting to make my actions menus "prettier".  :)  Using the code below...

```
  ActionMenu["Print Factorials", {"4!" :> Print[4!], "7!" :> Print[7!], 
  "10!" :> Print[10!]}]
```

results in...

[image]

1. I would like the palette look of the Action Menu box to also appear for the item list box.  As you can see in the picture above the item list box is rounded at the corners.
2. Also, I would like the item list box to be justified right below instead of overlapping the ActionMenu box as seen in the pic above.
3. I would also like it the item list box to have the same width as the Actionmenu box.  Is this possible?

I think all 3 of these would make for much cleaner looking Action menu.  Ideas?

Comment: stand corrected but i think some of these behaviours are OS dependent

Comment: I see.  I am running Mathematica 10.3 on OS X 10.11.1

Comment: Have you tried playing with the options `MenuAppearance` and `FieldSize`?

Comment: Interesting note: In 10.3.1 ActionMenu [is supposed to have some improvements](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history.html), but I didn't notice what the difference is yet (I'm also on OS X).

Comment: @IstvánZachar - Yes.  Field size solves my Question #3.  Thank you.  I do not see any documentation on MenuAppearance.  Did you mean Appearance?  Appearance does't solve Questions 1 or 2 as far as I can tell.

Comment: There is an option `MenuAppearance`, though undocumented. Just check with `Options@ActionMenu`. Not that I know how to use it, but it worth exploring a bit.

Comment: I tried messing around with it a bit.  I couldn't get anything to change.

Comment: @Szabolcs - I noticed that Kuba posted this question in the Wolfram Community... see here:  http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/760561?p_p_auth=CyNmR8Yn